# How To Dynamically Add, Remove Input Textbox And Get Values In Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have Blazor server app, and how can I dynamically add new input textboxes on button click and remove it and get the value of all the input textboxes on submit button click so that I can save them in the database.

```
@for (int i = count; i >= 1; i--)
{
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" @bind-value="@text_val" /> <p>@i</p><p>@count</p>
</div>

}
<div class="row">
<button @onclick=@(() => Increment())>Add User</button>
</div>

@code {
        public string text_val;
        public int count = 1;
        public void Increment()
        {
          count = count + 1;
        }

}
```

Any help will be great. Thank you

Comment: what did you try so far ? , post same code so we can help you

Comment: Do you know  the textboxes that you want to show/hide at compile time ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Initialize a list of values as I have done with the `values` list here. I have added an <kbd>Add Users</kbd> button here and a method to be executed on click called `AddValue()` which adds a new empty string to the list. This will trigger a state change and Blazor will automatically re-execute the for loop and add an additional text box.
- The for loop adds an `<input type="text">` for each item in the list and the `@onchange` event will update the corresponding value in the list using the `UpdateValue()` method when the value of the textbox changes and loses focus. If you want the value to update the textbox every time it changes without losing focus, use `@oninput` instead.
- I have also added a <kbd>Remove</kbd> button and a `RemoveValue()` method to remove the textboxes and values.
- You can access the values of the `values` list in any method. When the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button is clicked, `HandleSubmit()` will be called and you can access and validate the list/textbox values there.

*If you are using a loop variable like `i` that changes on every iteration in a lambda expression, make sure that you first copy it to a local variable. Otherwise, since the lambda expression will [capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions) the variable `i`, and when the lambda executes later, the latest value of `i` will be used which after the end of the loop will be equal to the length of the list.*
I have done this by copying `i` first to a local variable `index` here.

```
<div class="container border">
    <h3>Users</h3>
    <hr />
    <button @onclick="AddValue" class="btn btn-primary">Add User</button>

    @for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        <div>
            <input type="text" @onchange="(e) => UpdateValue(index, e.Value.ToString())" value="@values[i]" />
            <button @onclick="() => RemoveValue(index)" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Remove</button>
        </div>
    }
    <hr />
    <div>
        <button @onclick="HandleSubmit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <hr />
    @for (int j = 0; j < values.Count; j++)
    {
        <p>@values[j]</p>
    }
</div>
@code {
    private List<string> values = new List<string>();

    private void AddValue() => values.Add("");
    private void UpdateValue(int i, string value) => values[i] = value;
    private void RemoveValue(int i) => values.RemoveAt(i);
    private void HandleSubmit()
    {
        //Access and validate the values list here
    }
}
```

See it working on [BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/qhqazi3b).