# How can I add controls dynamically and tie to a model with Blazor Server?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I found [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67565103/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-input-textbox-and-get-values-in-blazor-server/76565267#76565267) here on Stack Overflow that I think would accomplish what I would like to do.  Someone posted an answer with an example in BlazorFiddle, however it is not working there.  I would like to know how this can be accomplished by tying this to a model if possible.  Or would it make more sense to have a component and add it dynamically?  Basically the users want a row in a table with a few values to be added, a couple text, and a date with a date picker.  They would like a "+" button to add more to the table.   I am new to Blazor and have found a few things, but getting confused and would like to learn the correct way of implementing something like this.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: See if this can help, where dynamic controls and bound to model https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71283001/bind-expandoobject-to-mudblazor-form-controls/71283823#71283823

Comment: This sounds like "Tell me how to write a generic form builder". "implementing something like this" is a big task.  What starts out as "just a couple of text boxes and a date field" grows. The number and type of controls increase and the complexity increases exponentially.  For example, you need a select.  How do you know where to get the list?  How do you validate the input?  Search the Internet for examples.  There's a reason you won't find many!

Comment: See this question and the comments - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75865665/blazor-genericeditform

Comment: @isherwood Yes, I understand this is not the best format for a question, it's just that I've been searching and trying things for so long that I just didn't know how else to ask

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - Yes, I understand your point.  I have run into this situation in other languages as well.  It is just something the business wants and I have told them this may not be possible

Comment: @JimboJones - No problem, it's a very common question on here.  What I call a *Holy Grail Project*.  I built one once for SharePoint.  What a monster it evolved into.  It ended up quicker to write the edit forms that configure the configuration file.  The problem is they say simple, but it never stays that way for long!

Comment: My modern approach is to boiler plate everything so I inherit from an `EditFormBase` and I'm just creating the layout with composite edit controls for each field.